# Really simple query giving error in SQL syntax

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, sql

I'm sure this is a simple oversight but I cannot seem to narrow it down:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "icrm_folders";
 $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s", $tablename );
 //$sql results in SELECT * FROM 'wp_icrm_folders'
 $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

This seems to result in nothing! My debugger shows an error on $wpdb object under last_error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_icrm_folders'' at line 1
```

Now I ran the query `SELECT * FROM 'wp_icrm_folders'` directly in phpmyadmin and that gives me an error because wp_icrm_folders is inside `'` the query executes fine if I remove the apostrophes or replace them with the grave accent/character.

PHP Version 5.3.3-7

MySQL Version 5.1.63

WordPress 3.5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `$wpdb->prepare` with table names. `prepare` will quote your table names that will result in incorrect SQL.

It is unnecessary overhead as well. Your table name should never, and in your case isn't, be user-supplied data. You have no need to escape it. 'prepare' is for use on user-supplied data, such as data from a form or a `$_GET` parameter.

You have no user-supplied data so all you need is

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$tablename}");
```

Comment: So if I wanted to have $_GET parameters I would use:
`$wpdb->get_results(wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$tablename} WHERE folder_id = %d", $_GET['folder_id']));` as a simple example?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `$_GET` parameters are always strings so using `%d` may not work, unless you cast `$_GET['folder_id']` to an integer first, but basically that is it.

Comment: So basically it's broken by design because "table names are never user supplied" aka "64k is enough for everyone".

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not write the query in proper way. So here is just little example may be it help you.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

and that's it.

Comment: No that's definitely not it. Tried it - it doesn't solve the problem.