# Quotes in table name

Tags: wpdb

Since WP3.5, `prepare()` accepts placeholders as a security measure, instead of just appending the argument to the query.  Therefore, `$wpdb->prefix` needs to become a second parameter, called by `%s`:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM %s WHERE answer !=' '", $wpdb->prefix . "faq_questions" ) );
```

However, doing that returns the table name in quotes:

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM 'wp_faq_questions' WHERE answer !=' '`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

You can't, but it isn't broken. You are telling `prepare` to use a string. A string will be quoted. It isn't meant to generate MySQL syntax, which is what you are asking it to do. Your tablename is more a MySQL command or keyword than a string value. That isn't what `prepare` is for.

`prepare` is meant to operate on user supplied data. Your tablename is not-- well, shouldn't be-- user supplied data so you don't need to "prepare" it. It is unnecessary. Just construct the tablename in the SQL itself:

```
"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."faq_questions WHERE answer !=' '"
```

See:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/93861/21376

Answer (score 0):

You have some choices. Whitelisting is a good option - that is, check against an array of allowed field names and only add the ORDERBY clause if one of the field names is recognized.

`if ( in_array( $table_name, ['faq_questions', 'faq_responses', 'some_other_table'] ) )...`

Otherwise, WordPress has a nice function built just for you:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_sql_orderby

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution:

```
$table = 'my_table';
$field = 'my_field';
$value = 'my_value';

$wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM %i WHERE %i = %s', $table, $field, $value);

// Output:
//   SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_field` = 'my_value'
```

Comment: Please add a description of the code solution. So people understand the answer with content and not only code.